# Irritating object keys and there values from 1 line of an object with es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a object with one line of keys and there values.
I am trying to map these keys and display the values.

```
   productObj = {id:0, name:"toy", price:10, description:null, inventory:7 }

   productObj.map((product, index) => { 
      if(product.inventory > 0){
       return(
          <div>Product Inventory: {product.inventory}</div>
        );
      }
      if(product.description){
        return(
          <p>{product.description}</p>
        );
      }
    })
```

This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

I used:

```
  const keys = Object.keys(productObj)
```

and I was able to map the array of key values.

However, this means I would have to re use the original object to get the values to the keys.

I'm sure there is better way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to `map` the keys at all? From the question, it looks like you need just an if-else

Comment: Do you have array of objects of single object?

Comment: I am trying to list out the products attributes only when they exist.

Comment: You can use `Object.values` instead of `Object.key`

Comment: I think coverting my object to something like this  `productObj = [{id:0}, {name:"toy"}, {price:10}, {description:null}, {inventory:7}]` would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` if you want both key and value.

```
return Object.entries(productObj).filter(x => x[1]).map(([k,v]) => <div>{`k:{v}`}</div>)
```

*"Using the example above. if( inventory>2 ) Is it possible to implement this if statement. Reduce"*.

You can create an object with different keys which have function for different keys.

```
const obj = {
   invetory:a => a > 2
}
return Object.entries(productObj)
            .filter(([k,v]) => obj[k] ? obj[k]() : x[1])
            .map(([k,v]) => <div>{`k:{v}`}</div>)
```

Comment: I get `productObj.map is not a function` , this is what my object looks like when empty `{"id":null,"strn":null,"typ":null,"eth_prc":null,"fth_prc":null,"hlf_prc":null,"zip_prc":null,"prc":null,"name":null,"eth_siz":null,"img2":null,"brand":null,"des":null}` . I am just trying to list these values into elements when they are not null. So this generate a empty list. If one of these keys had a value it needs to be listed.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I am working on how to implement the solution. Looks like it can work but i'm trying to figure out how to use it for my purpose in react.

Comment: ok this is working. `const ListedObj = Object.entries(productInfo).filter(x => x[1]).filter(Boolean).map(([k,v]) => <div>{k +" "+ v}</div>` is returning a list of only keys an values that arent null.  May I ask how to implement the if statement?  Using the example above. `if( inventory>2 )`  Is it possible to implement this if statement. Reduce?

Comment: @AaronTomlinson Are there conditions for every `key:value` or only invetory

Comment: I got what i was looking for by doing this
`const ListedObj = Object.entries(productInfo).filter(x => x[1]).filter(Boolean).map(([k,v]) => (k === "type" || k === "strain")?<div>{k +" "+ v}</div>:null)`
Is this good practice? A console log of this variable looks like
`,,,,,,,,,,,,,,[object Object],,[object Object]`,
but it rendered in the HTML like I wanted without any commas.

Comment: @AaronTomlinson You are really mixing up two situations. I have answered _"Using the example above. if( inventory>2 ) Is it possible to implement this if statement"_. For logging an object use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to prevent `[object Object]`